# How to parse csv in PHP having multiline data in a column

Tags: php, parsing, csv

Consider s CSV file like this

```
item1,"description 1"
item2,"description 2"
item3,"description 3
description 3 continues on new line"
item4,"description 4"
```

which should be parsed like this

```
item1,"description 1"
item2,"description 2"
item3,"description 3 description 3 continues on new line"
item4,"description 4"
```

Is there a way to parse this CSV in PHP which has multiline values?

Comment: @goreSplatter, or just use an existing one.

Comment: @Bart Sorry I left out the other obvious solution.

Comment: possible duplicate of [parse csv file php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3930061/parse-csv-file-php)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[`fgetcsv`](http://php.net/fgetcsv) should be able to properly parse this.
I wouldn't recommend doing this by hand anyway, there are many such gotchas in parsing CSV.

Comment: The problem is I was using fgets read line from file then str_getcsv to parse string instead of using only fgetcsv. It was working fine with single line columns but not multiline ones. Even tough PHP.net says fgetcsv "Gets line from file" seems that "line" here is not actual line in plain text file but the whole actual row with all multiline data.

Comment: I came along the same issue today and made a little [test](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/rd6-new), that proofs your statement about _lines_ referring to _csv-rows_ and not to actual _file-lines_.

Comment: I was hoping to use `str_getcsv` as it doesn't have to load the entire file into memory, just the row that is being red. `fgetcsv` does work with multiline CSV fields, but `str_getcsv` apparently does not.

Comment: @Erfan `fgetcsv` also only reads one line at a time from an open file handle…!?

Answer (score 20):

Here are some working examples how to do it. I am using fgetcsv:

CSV in string variable $CsvString:

```
$fp = tmpfile();
fwrite($fp, $CsvString);
rewind($fp); //rewind to process CSV
while (($row = fgetcsv($fp, 0)) !== FALSE) {
    print_r($row);
}
```

CSV in file:

```
if (($handle = fopen("test.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
  while (($row = fgetcsv($handle, 0, ",")) !== FALSE) {
    print_r($row);
  }
  fclose($handle);
}
```

Comment: Excellent answer.  I have CSV's uploaded by the user with \r line endings (I have no idea why), and had to strreplace prior to parsing CSV.  Since str_getcsv doesn't handle multiple lines, and some rows have new lines in them, this (while hackish, putting stuff in a temp file just to make PHP parse it) works.

Answer (score 12):

Based on [StanleyD](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1980067/stanleyd) answer, but using a temp memory block (rather than writing to disk) for better performance:

```
$fp = fopen('php://temp','r+');
fwrite($fp, $CsvString);
rewind($fp); //rewind to process CSV
while (($row = fgetcsv($fp, 0)) !== FALSE) {
    print_r($row);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is a quick and easy solution using the PHP function [`str_getcsv()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php)

Here is an example:

```
function parse_csv( $filename_or_text, $delimiter=',', $enclosure='"', $linebreak="\n" )
{
    $return = array();
    
    if(false !== ($csv = (filter_var($filename_or_text, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL) ? file_get_contents($filename_or_text) : $filename_or_text)))
    {
        $csv = trim($csv);
        $csv = mb_convert_encoding($csv, 'UTF-16LE');   
        
        foreach(str_getcsv($csv, $linebreak, $enclosure) as $row){
            $col = str_getcsv($row, $delimiter, $enclosure);
            $col = array_map('trim', $col);
            $return[] = $col;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        throw new \Exception('Can not open the file.');
        $return = false;
    }
    
    return $return;
}
```

Imagine a situation where you need a function that works with both URL and comma delimited text. This is exactly the function that works like that. Just simply insert a CSV URL or comma separated text and it work nicely.

Comment: No multiline, see @Erfan