# php CSV import generated from MS Excel

Tags: php, excel, csv, csv-import

According to standards specified here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values

and a CSV file generated from MS Excel, I wonder how can we import CSV file in php in this 
case:

- normally, CSV cells are not enclosed in double quotes ("), but will be enclosed when there is a comma (,), double quote (") or new line character (\n) in cell value.
- double quotes in cell are replaced with twice double quotes (" => "").
- e.g. testCell 1,"test,comma cell 2","testCell ""double quote"" 3",testCell 4

Now, the issue is, how can we identify/separate each cell while reading such CSV as the cells may be enclosed with double quote or may not be.

Comment: possible duplicate of [parse csv file php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3930061/), [How to parse csv in PHP having multiline data in a column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4732953/)

Comment: @outis I don't know about that.  Excel usually outputs CSV that's nonstandard compliant.  `fgetcsv` doesn't like it one bit.

Comment: @Phoenix: maybe, but `fgetcsv` works with both the specific case described and the test data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@outis: you were right (fgetcsv works with both the specific cases). Issue was with parsing some German characters before applying fgetcsv.