# Reading .csv into a PHP array

Tags: php, arrays, algorithm, csv, multidimensional-array

I have a PHP routine that reads a .csv file that has been uploaded to my site.

The number of fields in the file may be different from upload to upload.

I want to be able to establish the size of the .csv file (the number of fields) and then store its contents in an array.

This is what I have so far:

```
//get the csv file 
$file = $_FILES[csv1][tmp_name]; 
$handle = fopen($file,"r"); 

//loop through the csv file and insert into array
$dataline = fgetcsv($handle,1000,",","'");
$fieldnum = count($dataline);

$recordloop = 0;

while ($dataline) 
{ 

    for ($fieldloop=0; $fieldloop <$fieldnum; $fieldloop++)
    {
        //this is the bit that is wrong
        $dataarray[]=array($dataline[$fieldloop]);
    }

    $data = fgetcsv($handle,1000,",","'");
    $recordloop++;
}
```

If for example, there are 30 fields and 200 records I am trying to get the array to be of the structure `$dataarray[200][30]`.

How do I get the data into the array of this structure?

Example .csv:

```
Row 1 will be field headings
Name, Gender, Ethnicity, DOB, etc .... the number of fields is not fixed - it could be from 30 to 40 fields in this row

Rows 2 onwards will be the records
John, M, British, 10/04/49, etc
Simon, M, British, 04/03/65, etc
```

ANSWER - did just what I wanted

```
$file = $_FILES[csv1][tmp_name]; 
$handle = fopen($file,"r"); 

$matrix = array();
while (($row = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) 
{
$matrix[] = $row;
}
```

Comment: can you edit with a csv sample?

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17761172/php-csv-string-to-array or 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4732953/how-to-parse-csv-in-php-having-multiline-data-in-a-column or 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2805427/how-to-extract-data-from-csv-file-in-php or 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3930061/parse-csv-file-php.

Take your pick.

Answer (score 20):

You already have this kind of implementation in PHP:

```
$csv = array_map('str_getcsv', file('someCSVfile.csv'));
```

Explanation:

- `str_getcsv()` - Parse a CSV string into an array.
- `file()`     - Reads entire file into an array.
- `array_map(Function, Array)`- Returns an array containing all the elements of the array after applying the callback function to each one.

Example output:

```
//CSV
NAME,CLASS,ROOM
Sally,2018,312
Belinda,2017,148

//OUTPUT:
Array(
       [0] => Array([0] => NAME,    [1] => CLASS, [2] => ROOM), 
       [1] => Array([0] => Sally,   [1] => 2018,  [2] => 312),
       [2] => Array([0] => Belinda, [1] => 2017,  [2] => 148)
)
```

**Associative keys**

Two quick functions to parse with associative keys - both based on the `array_map` method:

METHOD 1: running twice

```
function assoc_getcsv($csv_path) {
    $r = array_map('str_getcsv', file($csv_path));
    foreach( $r as $k => $d ) { $r[$k] = array_combine($r[0], $r[$k]); }
    return array_values(array_slice($r,1));
}
```

METHOD 2: running once

```
function assoc_getcsv($csv_path) {
    $f = array();
    function parse_csv_assoc($str,&$f){ 
        if (empty($f)) { $f = str_getcsv($str); }
        return array_combine($f, str_getcsv($str));         
    }
    return array_values(array_slice(array_map('parse_csv_assoc', file($csv_path), $f),1));
}
```

Example output:

```
//CSV
NAME,CLASS,ROOM
Sally,2018,312
Belinda,2017,148

//OUTPUT:
Array(
       [0] => Array([NAME] => Sally,   [CLASS] => 2018,  [ROOM] => 312),
       [1] => Array([NAME] => Belinda, [CLASS] => 2017,  [ROOM] => 148)
)
```

Comment: That's an interestingly short way of getting the job done. Just out of curiosity - have you compared the speed of this and working with `SplFileObject` and an `Iterator`?

Comment: No -> I'm using this function for month and parsing 11K CSV in ~1-2secs

Comment: This definitely is twice as fast as using an `SplFileObject`. Here's my [test](https://gist.github.com/steve-todorov/929c074788011aff3230).

Comment: @tftd great test! are you up to test the two other methods too?

Answer (score 4):

this function will read a CSV and generate a multi-dimensional array

```
function fromCSVFile( $file) {
    // open the CVS file
    $handle = @fopen( $file, "r");
    if ( !$handle ) {
        throw new \Exception( "Couldn't open $file!" );
    }

    $result = [];

    // read the first line
    $first = strtolower( fgets( $handle, 4096 ) );
    // get the keys
    $keys = str_getcsv( $first );

    // read until the end of file
    while ( ($buffer = fgets( $handle, 4096 )) !== false ) {

        // read the next entry
        $array = str_getcsv ( $buffer );
        if ( empty( $array ) ) continue;

        $row = [];
        $i=0;

        // replace numeric indexes with keys for each entry
        foreach ( $keys as $key ) {
            $row[ $key ] = $array[ $i ];
            $i++;
        }

        // add relational array to final result
        $result[] = $row;
    }

    fclose( $handle );
    return $result;
}
```

So if your .CSV file looks like this:

```
Name,Gender,Ethnicity,DOB
John,M,British,10/04/49
Simon,M,British,04/03/65
```

You will get this:

```
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => John
            [gender] => M
            [ethnicity] => British
            [dob] => 10/04/49
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => Simon
            [gender] => M
            [ethnicity] => British
            [dob] => 04/03/65
        )

)
```

Comment: Thanks, and that  is great but I don't actually want the first row to become the key. I want them to remain in the first row of the array.

Answer (score 4):

1.csv:

```
Name,Gender,Ethnicity,DOB
John,M,British,10/04/49
Simon,M,British,04/03/65
```

Use `file()` to read the csv file into an array, then iterate through this array and get all the fields into an array element with `explode()` and make your new `$array`

```
<?php

$file = '1.csv';
$content = file($file);

$array = array();

for($i = 1; $i < count($content); $i++) {
    $line = explode(',', $content[$i]);
    for($j = 0; $j < count($line); $j++) {
        $array[$i][$j + 1] = $line[$j];
    }   
}   

print_r($array);

?>
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [1] => John
            [2] => M
            [3] => British
            [4] => 10/04/49

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [1] => Simon
            [2] => M
            [3] => British
            [4] => 04/03/65

        )

)
```

If you want get *record:2* and *field:4* you can do this:

```
echo $array[2][4];
```

Output:

```
04/03/65
```

Comment: @RichardGriffiths do you got some advance?

Comment: ? - I have found the answer. I have edited the question to show the answer. Thanks for your help.